# SQLTrackerStore not creating tables

Tags: mysql, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I want to store the chats in my MySql database for that i followed below process but i don’t get any error. I can’t see any tables got created when i run my application and chat with the bot. Please help below is my work.My rasa_core version is 0.12.2 and rasa_nlu version is 0.13.8

**endpoints.yml**

```
action_endpoint:
  url: "http://localhost:5055/webhook"

tracker_store:
    type: SQL
    dialect: "mysql+pymysql"
    url: "localhost"
    db: "rasa" 
    username: "test"
    password: "test"
```

after that i run the below command but it is not creating any table.

> python -m rasa_core.run --enable_api -d models\dialogue -u
>   models\nlu\default\weathernlu -o models\out.log --endpoints
>   endpoints.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQLTrackerStore was added in [Rasa version 1.0](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst#100---2019-05-21). Hence this does not work in your older `0.12.2` version of Rasa Core. Please upgrade to Rasa 1.0 if you want to use the SQLTrackerStore.
Please note that Rasa Core and Rasa NLU were merged in version 1.0 of `rasa`.

Comment: then for my version can i use redis or mongodb ?